# SQL stored procedure conditional update for one of the cloumns

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this `update` statement in my SP:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[mySP]
      @ID INT
    , @valA NVARCHAR(500) 
    , @valB NVARCHAR(500)
    , @valC NVARCHAR(500)
    , @flag BIT = 0
UPDATE mt
    SET mt.colA = @valA,
        mt.colB = @valB,
        mt.colC = @valC,
        mt.colD = GETUTCDATE()
    FROM dbo.mytable mt
    WHERE mt.ID = @ID
```

I want to change it to update colD only if @flag is 1. What would be the best and efficient way without impacting the performance of the SP much?

Comment: Use `case when @flag = 1 then...` expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would seem the easiest way would be to use a `CASE` expression:

```
mt.colD = CASE @Flag WHEN 1 THEN GETUTCDATE() ELSE mt.ColD END
```

Comment: in order to know the impact of this change do I have to benchmark it? I am just concerned that I do not end up adding a delay considering that this SP will be called thousands of time in less than 5 mins.

Comment: This isn't going to have any impact compared to the query you already had, @favier .

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[mySP]
      @ID INT
    , @valA NVARCHAR(500) 
    , @valB NVARCHAR(500)
    , @valC NVARCHAR(500)
    , @flag BIT = 0
UPDATE mt
    SET mt.colA = @valA,
        mt.colB = @valB,
        mt.colC = @valC,
        mt.colD  = case when  @flag = 1 then  GETUTCDATE() else  mt.colD END
    FROM dbo.mytable mt
    WHERE mt.ID = @ID
```